# List items not sliding for new items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nested unordered list that I want to expand accordion-like for new sub-items when a parent is clicked.

The functionality is working fine, but the parent list isn't sliding down to accomodate the newly visible sub-list (so the sub-list just slides on top of the unmoving parent list). I tried this [on a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VPG6/34/) and strangely it worked fine there. I'm guessing it has something to do with the CSS I'm using to format the list?

The code....

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        news
        <ul>
            <li>2013</li>
            <li>2012</li>
            <li>2011</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>scores</li>
    <li>standings</li>
    <li>the ddl</li>
    <li>records</li>
    <li>teams</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#nav-bar ul li').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children().slideDown('fast');
        $(this).siblings().children().slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav-bar {  /*left bar*/
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    height: inherit;
}

#nav-bar ul {   /*main menu*/
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav-bar ul li {    /*main menu item*/
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
}

#nav-bar ul li ul { /*sub-menu*/
    display: none;
}

#nav-bar ul li ul li {  /*sub-menu item*/
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    color: #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you fixed  an height where it should be , IMHO, a min-height:
http://jsfiddle.net/7VPG6/36/

```
#nav-bar > ul>  li {    /*main menu item*/
    min-height: 75px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
}
```

take a look at : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have given me the accordion effect, but now I have a new problem: my sub-list items are also `75px`, instead of the desired `35px` as specified in the css. I tried changing it to `max-height: 35px` to no avail.

Comment: So you need to specify CSS only to <li> of first-level : http://jsfiddle.net/7VPG6/36/ Answer edited see CSS

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The 75px height was already specified at the <li> of the first level. However, I changed the second-level <li> height to min-height, and that seems to have done the trick as well. Don't know why, exactly...

Comment: just see the CSS i wrote with selector : '>' , it applies the rules only to the <li> directly child of <ul> child #nav-bar. if not direct child selector, then height is applied to every single <li> child of #nav-bar <ul> .

Comment: Oh, I did not understand the usefulness of the '>' selector, thank you! I thought `#nav-bar ul` and `#nav-bar > ul` were synonymous. Good information, thank you!

Comment: great!, take time to look at CSS selectors, it is your main tool to build your style sheets :)   http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/